# python pandas float value comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I have a threshold value set at 2.0

```
threshold = 2.0
```

and a dataframe with a column A containing float values that I am performing a Boolean search on.

```
df[ df.A > threshold ]
```

however, this result set leads to rows where the value is equal to the threshold, when they should be excluded. Please advise.

The following is the output of `df.head()`:

```
timestamp   
2010-05-07 09:45:00     -2
2010-05-07 10:00:00     -2
2010-05-07 10:15:00     -2
2010-05-07 10:30:00     -2
2010-05-07 10:45:00     -2
```

Comment: You have column B but you compare with A ? Show part of dataframe and result. Try diffenet comparition.

Comment: what is the datatype of the contents of column `A` ?

Comment: the datatype is float64

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you have a value such as `2.000000001` and it is rounded and only showing `2.000` for example.  So your `threshold` appears it isn't working but it really is.  In the absence of further information it is tough to tell though.  An example of your dataset would help.

Comment: Perhaps you're meaning to do `df[df.A > theshold]`?